# How to extract value from a JSON string with no Key?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a JSON column in one of the tables, and the JSON column has no key or property, only the value.

I tried to parse the column with `JSON_Query` and `JSON_Value`, but both of these functions only work if the JSON string has a key, but in my situation, the JSON string has no key.

So how can I parse the column from the top table to the bottom table in SQL Server like the image below?

[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server? That does not look like valid JSON, so you probably won't be able to use the JSON functions.

Comment: Actually OPENJSON might work if you can convince SQL Server that the column is valid JSON :) Try something like this `SELECT value
FROM OPENJSON([JSON Column],'$')`

Comment: Actually probably not unless you have valid JSON formatting. But your post doesn't show that.

Comment: You have a simple array.  If 2016+ take a look at string_split()

Comment: This is a valid JSON column since I ran the ISJSON test with it. And this column actually have a key in a different table, but the developer processed the key and value into different columns in SQL. Neither OPENJSON and string_split() work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT, [JSONColumn] NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @Table(ID,[JSONColumn])VALUES
     (151616,'["B0107C57WO","B066EYU4IY"]')
    ,(151617,'["B0088MD64S"]')
;

SELECT t.ID,j.[value]
FROM @Table t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.JSONColumn) j
;
```

Comment: This works great so far, but since there are millions of record within the JSON Column, I will not be able to specify the value one by one. So instead of inserting specific value, can you do it as Id and JSON Column are columns within a SQL table? So I can extract the value from every JSON record instead of having to specify one by one?

Comment: SELECT t.ID,j.[value] FROM [UseYourTableName] AS [t] CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.[ThatTableJSONColumnName]) AS [j];

Comment: you rocked! Thank you so much for the help.